# How can there be a race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition, synchronized

why can there be a race condition in my code, when all accounts are synchronized?

```
class Transfer implements Runnable {

    Konto fromAccount;
    Konto toAccount;
    Integer amount;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (fromAccount) {
            if (fromAccount.book(-amount)) {
                toAccount.book(amount);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 

        Account thomas = new Account(1234, 100);
        Account mathias = new Account(5678, 100);
        Thread transfer1 = new Thread(new Transfer(80, thomas, mathias));
        Thread transfer2 = new Thread(new Transfer(95, mathias, thomas));
        transfer1.start();
        transfer2.start();
        transfer1.join();
        transfer2.join();
}
```

From my understanding, transfer1 locks its fromAccount (thomas) and transfer2 locks its fromAccount (mathias) so shouldn't they both end up in a deadlock?

Comment: Do have a deadlock or a race condition? You mention both, but they are different. Looks to me like you have a potential race but not a deadlock on a quick glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code `toAccount.book(amount)` doesn't run with the synchronized protection.

So technically it could happen that thread1 holds lock on `thomasAccount` and thread2 holds lock on `mathiasAccount` but the thread2 still runs book on `thomasAccount` at the same time as the thread1 runs book on `thomasAccount`. This could result into inconsistency as one of the thread can ignore the result from the second thread.

Simply any thread operating on any account must first lock (synchronize) the account, no matter whether it's plus or minus.

To avoid deadlock, make the accounts comparable (or use some id of the account) and lock the accounts always in the ascending order. Or you can use hash for this but in case the hash is the same, you need some global lock then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still don't fully understand one thing: 
If thread1 holds lock on `thomasAccount` , how can thread2 run book on `thomasAccount` ?

Comment: The thread2 stops only when it attempts to acquire the same lock. The call to `book()` itself doesn't performs the locking.

Comment: Thanks again, you're really helping me out here!
So if I understand that correctly, a locked object can still be accessed from other threads, by for example a method-call, as long as it's not trying to acquire a lock on it. Is that right?

Comment: @Numb3rs : Exactly. Only when the method is marked as synchronized, it acquires the lock on the object (`this`) prior to the method execution.

Comment: @Numb3rs, Synchronizing on an object does not prevent other threads from using the object.  It only prevents other threads from _synchronizing_ on the same object at the same time.

Comment: Please explain on deadlock you mentioned in the answer probably a bit with sample code showing deadlock and correct code which avoids deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Your `run` method only synchronizes on `fromAccount`, not `toAccount`. Code that isn't synchronized is not blocked by synchronized code; the two threads trying to access something must **both** synchronize on it in order to serialize access.

So your `run` method must synchronize not just on `fromAccount`, but also on `toAccount`, in order for any synchronizing on `toAccount` to make it wait.